# Is there an alternative for Azure Cloud Services that can scale out faster?

Tags: c#, performance, azure, scalability, azure-cloud-services

We currently run our service as an Azure Cloud Service with a web role. It's rather convenient to deploy (from the .cspkg) and manage OS changes (the Guest OS images thing) and we even download rarely changing dependencies from blob storage and unpack them.

However scaling out is very slow - our code computes various metrics and at some moment it decides to scale out and issues a [Change Deployment Configuration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee460809.aspx) Management Service request. Then some magic happens inside Azure and something like 5-10 minutes later we have new service instances running our startup code - control finally gets into `RoleEntryPoint.OnStart()`. That's very slow for us - we'd like to have `RoleEntryPoint.OnStart()` invoked something like 5-10 *seconds* instead of 5-10 minutes after the scale-out request.

Is there any PaaS-style alternative to Cloud Services within Azure which is known to scale out faster?

Comment: Your question reads as an recommendation question, which is off-topic AFAIK. Not sure if understand it incorrectly.

Comment: For that amount of start-up time I would almost suggest to have a hot-standby, and spin up a new hot-standby once the former one is taken into rotation.

Comment: I personally haven't used it but have you looked at Azure Service Fabric (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/service-fabric-overview/)? From what I understand, it has extremely fast deployment (seconds instead of minutes). This is also being dubbed as "Cloud Services v2".

Comment: @GauravMantri Is this fast deployment claimed (or better validated) anywhere for Service Fabric?

Comment: Please read bullet point #7 here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/service-fabric-overview/#key-capabilities. Another thing you may want to think about is that Service Fabric is all about Micro Services. I don't think we can take a Cloud Service as is and run it in a Service Fabric Cluster.

Comment: While I can't really recommend anything specific (since only you know your app details), there are on-demand compute resources available, called [Azure Functions](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/functions/). You may want to look into this to see if you can take advantage of this service.

Comment: Service Fabric deployments are very fast compared to Cloud Services, but that is because the actual VM that will host the service is already running. You'd already have a VMs running in the cluster and then new instances of your service/code would be deployed quickly to those machines. The benefit you can have is fast deployments as well as using those VMs for other services as well. If you have to add a VM to the cluster, that can take minutes.

Comment: It might help if you provide a little more info on what your app is doing. Is it made up of mostly backend processing? Web site? API? All of the above? These all my have different answers.

Comment: @MikeWo It hosts an ASP.NET web site and also runs background processing with unmanaged code - some heavy computations.

Answer (score 0):

The alternative would be App Service (web apps). You won't have the same control as with cloud services but they can still be customized pretty well, and they scale out (and up) really fast.